# Nodejs - Return array of key-value pair by adding values with same key

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

I have the following array of objects:

```
const list = [
  {points: 3, name:'bob'},
  {points: 1, name:'john'},
  {points: 5, name:'john'},
  {points: 2, name:'john'},
  {points: 8, name:'john'},
  {points: 0, name:'bob'},
  {points: 2, name:'bob'},
  {points: 1, name:'bob'},
]
```

And I want to end up with and object that returns a list of data-sets that contains the sum of points for each name like:

```
const list2 = [
  {name: 'bob', points: 6}, // sum of all of bob's points
  {name: 'john', points: 16}
]
```

I need this so that I can use the resulting data set to generate a line chart.

Is there a way to do this, preferably using `ramda.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var combine = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')), //=> {bob: [bob_obj_1, bob_obj_2, ...], john: [ ... ]}
  map(pluck('points')),  //=> {bob: [3, 0, 2, 1], john: [1, 5, 2, 8]}
  map(sum)               //=> {bob: 6, john: 16}
)
```

Or you could use a `reduce`, but I think this is simpler.

**Update**: I misread the output format.  This fixes it:

```
var combine = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')), //=> {bob: [bob_obj_1, bob_obj_2, ...], john: [ ... ]}
  map(pluck('points')),  //=> {bob: [3, 0, 2, 1], john: [1, 5, 2, 8]}
  map(sum),              //=> {bob: 6, john: 16}
  toPairs,               //=> [["bob", 6], ["john", 16]]
  map(zipObj(['name', 'points'])) //=> [{name: "bob", points: 6}, 
                         //             {name: "john", points: 16}]
)
```

Comment: Smooth :) Actually your first answer would work Scott! Awesome

Comment: Glad it helps.  There's an updated version as well, which gives the originally expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly trivial use of [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
const list = [
  {points: 3, name:'bob'},
  {points: 1, name:'john'},
  {points: 5, name:'john'},
  {points: 2, name:'john'},
  {points: 8, name:'john'},
  {points: 0, name:'bob'},
  {points: 2, name:'bob'},
  {points: 1, name:'bob'},
]

const map = list.reduce((prev, next) => {
  // if the name has not already been observed, create a new entry with 0 points
  if (prev[next.name] == null) {
    prev[next.name] = 0;
  }

  // add the new points
  prev[next.name] += next.points;

  return prev;
}, {});

// map is now an object containing { [name]: [points] }
// convert this back into an array of entries
const list2 = Object.keys(map)
  .map(name => ({ name, points: map[name] }));

console.log(list2)
// [ { name: 'bob', points: 6 }, { name: 'john', points: 16 } ]
```